# Хочу передать значение с textarea в localStorage, не выходит js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, localstorage

Не отправляет данные и  когда ввожу текст в текстАреа,  комментарий добавляется без текста, помогите пожалуйста

```js
/////////////////////////////Announce all the objects that we need//////////////

let container = document.getElementById('middle'),
  rightContainer = document.getElementById('comm-container'),
  DeleteButt = document.querySelectorAll('.theme-delete'),
  field = document.getElementById('search'),
  theme = document.querySelectorAll('.theme-border'),
  txtArea = document.getElementById('addTxt');

////////////////create block of article///////////////
document.getElementById("AddElem").addEventListener('click', e => {
  let HoverBord = document.createElement('div');
  HoverBord.className = "theme-border";
  let theme = document.createElement('div');
  theme.className = "theme";
  HoverBord.appendChild(theme);
  let themButt = document.createElement('button');
  themButt.className = "theme-butt";
  themButt.innerHTML = field.value;
  theme.appendChild(themButt);
  let count = document.createElement('input');
  count.className = "theme-count";
  count.type = 'button';
  count.value = '0';
  theme.appendChild(count);
  let themDelete = document.createElement('button');
  themDelete.className = "theme-delete";
  themDelete.name = "del";
  themDelete.innerHTML = "Delete";
  theme.appendChild(themDelete);
  container.appendChild(HoverBord);
}, false);

document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  /////bubble  event for a new joined elemets
  const elem = e.target;

  if (elem.className === 'theme-delete') {
    elem.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(elem.parentNode);
  }
});
////////////search  name of article  and where we set the name//////
let search = e => {
  let filter, themeBlock, ThemeLabel, i;
  filter = field.value.toUpperCase();
  themeBlock = document.querySelectorAll('.theme');

  for (i = 0; i < themeBlock.length; i++) {
    ThemeLabel = themeBlock[i].querySelectorAll('.theme-butt')[0];
    if (ThemeLabel.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      themeBlock[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      themeBlock[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};
/////set key for tetex in area to local storage////////
setData = () => {
  localStorage.setItem('content', txtArea.value);
};

///////////////create  comment  block//////////
txtArea.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {

  if ((e.keyCode == 10 || e.keyCode == 13) && e.ctrlKey) {
    let StartComment = document.createElement('div');
    StartComment.className = "comment";
    let StartTable = document.createElement('table');
    StartTable.cellSpacing = "0";
    StartTable.cellPadding = "0";
    StartComment.appendChild(StartTable);
    let TR = document.createElement('tr');
    StartTable.appendChild(TR);
    let TD1 = document.createElement('td');
    TD1.className = "leftcol";
    TR.appendChild(TD1);
    let IMG = document.createElement('img');
    IMG.src = "http://www.iconhot.com/icon/png/south-park-1/300/cartman-ninja.png";
    IMG.alt = "test";
    TD1.appendChild(IMG);
    let TD2 = document.createElement('td');
    TD2.className = "txt";
    TD2.textContent = txtArea.value;
    /////  take  key to show
    TD2.textContent = localStorage.getItem('content');
    /////// object in local storage 
    txtArea.value = localStorage.getItem('content');
    TR.appendChild(TD2);
    setData();

    let parentArea = document.getElementsByClassName("Add-comment")[0]; //////// insert block of comments before text area
    let parentNode = parentArea.parentNode;
    parentNode.insertBefore(StartComment, parentArea);
    /////// add count point after we add block of comment
    let count = document.getElementById("counter");
    count.value = +parseInt(count.value) + 1;
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<section class="app">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2 left-side">
        <h1>DAIRY APP</h1>
        <span class="left-side--subtitle">Comment with no sense</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-5">
        <div class="middle" id="middle">
          <h2>Items</h2>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Type name here..." class="middle-search" id="search" onkeyup="search()">
          <button class="middle-addElement" id="AddElem">Add new</button>
          <div class="theme-border">
            <div class="theme">
              <button class="theme-butt">First item with custon name</button>
              <input type="button" value="132" class="theme-count">
              <button class="theme-delete" name="del">Delete</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="theme-border">
            <div class="theme">
              <button class="theme-butt">Second item is active</button>
              <input type="button" value="3" class="theme-count" id="counter">
              <button class="theme-delete" name="del">Delete</button>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-5">
        <div class="right-side" id="comm-container">
          <h3>Comments #2</h3>

          <div class="comment">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td class="leftcol"><img src="http://www.iconhot.com/icon/png/south-park-1/300/cartman-ninja.png" alt="test"></td>
                <td class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cvolupd impedit inventore nulla quibusdam? Ipsa magnam odio qui quisquam, repellat unde voluptates. At delectus, dicta excepturi explicabo placeat tempora ut voluptatem? veritatis voluptatem? Cupiditate, ipsum!</td>
              </tr>
            </table>

          </div>
          <div class="comment">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td class="leftcol"><img src="http://www.iconhot.com/icon/png/south-park-1/300/cartman-ninja.png" alt="test"></td>
                <td class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cvolupd impedit inventore nulla quibusdam? Ipsa magnam odio qui quisquam, repellat unde voluptates. At delectus, dicta excepturi explicabo placeat tempora ut voluptatem? veritatis voluptatem? Cupiditate, ipsum!</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="comment">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td class="leftcol"><img src="http://www.iconhot.com/icon/png/south-park-1/300/cartman-ninja.png" alt="test"></td>
                <td class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cvolupd impedit inventore nulla quibusdam? Ipsa magnam odio qui quisquam, repellat unde voluptates. At delectus, dicta excepturi explicabo placeat tempora ut voluptatem? veritatis voluptatem? Cupiditate, ipsum!</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="Add-comment">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td class="leftcol"><img src="http://www.iconhot.com/icon/png/south-park-1/300/cartman-ninja.png" alt="test"></td>
                <td class=""><textarea name="" id="addTxt" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Внутри функции setData не определен txtArea, попробуйте передать его в параметре

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что сбрасывается значение TextArea перед сохранением в localStorage

```
txtArea.value = localStorage.getItem('content');
TR.appendChild(TD2);
setData();
```

как вариант, можно сделать так...
в начале тела "if", слушателя "keydown"

```
const storagePropName = 'content';
const textAreaValue = txtArea.value;
```

после этого передать данные в "setData()"

```
setData(storagePropName, textAreaValue );
```

и изменить setData функцию...

```
setData = (storagePropName, value) => {
  localStorage.setItem(storagePropName, value);
};
```

Comment: попробовал, ничего не изменилось :(

Comment: посмотри это https://jsfiddle.net/nb0t7wp8/6/ . Я закомментировал строки 86,88. И обновил setData(), как писал раньше. Как результат, значение сохраняет в localStorage и новый элемент добавляется с введенным текстом. Мне не понятно для чего сохранять данные в localStorage, но может я не полностью понял задачу )

Comment: спасибо за помощь ! У меня все так же  не работает,  скопипастил код с фидла,   ничего не изменилось. На jsfiddle  смотрел, все отлично, хз в чем проблема

Comment: попробовал на другом пк, все работает, так что сорри : )